# Problems with including math parser "exprtk"

Tags: parsing, math, exprtk

Instead of programming a math parser myself, I'm trying to implement the exprtk ([exprtk](http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/)) into my project. It works fine if I implement it in a console project. However, it fails in my CLR project. The error says "Debug Assertion Failed [...] Expression: _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block) [...]". The error only occurs if I write the lines

```
parser<double> parser;
```

or

```
symbol_table<double> symbolTable;
symbolTable.add_constants();
```

Some internet sites say the _CrtlsValidHeapPointer expression error shows that a memory address is out of heap. But as the exprtk.hpp library works fine in a console application I assume there is another problem. Do you have an idea what the real problem could be?